# How can I understand if a memory address is used or not?

Tags: python, memory-management, free

I am doing some experiments with the Python garbage collector, I would like to check if a memory address is used or not. In the following example, I have de-referenced the string (`surely`) at `ls[2]`. If I run the garbage collector, I can still see `surely` at the original address. I would like to be sure that the address is now writable. Is there a way to check it in Python?

```
from ctypes import string_at
from sys import getsizeof
import gc
ls = ['This','will be','surely','deleted']
idsurely= id(ls[2]) 
sizesurely = getsizeof(ls[2])
ls[2] = 'probably'
print(ls)
print(string_at(idsurely,sizesurely))
gc.collect()
# I check there is nothing in the garbage
print(gc.garbage)
print(string_at(idsurely,sizesurely))
```

I am interested in this mainly from a theoretical point of view so I am not saying that is something that has practical usage. My goal is to show how memory works for a tutorial. I want to show that the data is still there and that just that the bytes at the address can be now written. So the output of the script is up to now as expected. I just want to prove the last passage.

Comment: You might find [this blog post](https://realpython.com/python-memory-management/) informative. It links to the relevant part of the Python source.

Comment: When a Python object is deleted, the memory addresses it formerly occupied still exist, and still contain the same values (other than the reference count now being zero) until such time as another object gets allocated at the same address.  The memory doesn't get cleared, as that would be wasted effort - whatever object eventually gets allocated to the same space will overwrite everything according to its needs.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks, yes I proved that until now using the code in the example, the last step I would like to prove that the memory assigned to the address can be now written, is there a way to check it? (of course, is only for a theoretical tutorial)

Comment: maybe doing something with an object's `__del__` method might be a good place to see when objects are reclaimed?

Comment: @SamMason: That'll work, though make sure you're doing it on modern Python; on Python prior to 3.4 IIRC (including 2.7), defining `__del__` on an object that participates in a reference cycle (which can happen inadvertently, e.g. because an exception was raised in the same scope, and the exception's traceback captured a reference to the frame containing both the exception and the `__del__`able object) means that it will never be cycle collected at all.

Comment: Of course the memory is writeable - it's impossible to control writeability of arbitrary-sized chunks of memory, that can only be done in terms of entire memory pages (and *that's* something that only the operating system does).  But writing to the memory of a deleted object is *utterly insane*, given that the memory is likely to be allocated to a new object at any moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible.

There is no central registry of used or unused memory addresses in Python. There isn't even a central registry of all objects (the cyclic GC doesn't know about all of them), and even if you had a registry of all objects, that wouldn't be enough to determine what memory locations are in use. Additionally, you can't just read arbitrary memory addresses, or write to arbitrary deallocated addresses. That'll quickly lead to segfaults or worse.

Finally, I would strongly advise against using this kind of thing in a tutorial even if you did find something to make it work. When you put something in a tutorial, a large fraction of people reading the tutorial are going to think it's something they're supposed to learn. Programming newbies should not be mislead into thinking that examining possibly-deallocated memory locations is something they should be doing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this was just an experiment as I said in the question is not something that has a practical usage. What I don't understand is how can Python know in what address are free and can allocate the memory if as you said there isn't a central registry?

Comment: @GM: The malloc implementation maintains enough metadata to be able to allocate and free memory. Python handles a bit of it on its own, but the information to do what you're looking for isn't there.

Answer (score 2):

Your experiments are way off base. `id` (solely as a CPython implementation detail) does get the memory address of the object in question, but we're talking about the Python object itself, not the data it contains. `sys.getsizeof` returns a number that roughly corresponds to how much memory the object occupies, but there is *no* guarantee that memory is contiguous.

By sheer coincidence, this *almost* works on `str` (though it will perform a buffer overread if the string in question has cached copies of its UTF-8 or `wchar_t` form, so you're risking crashing your program), but even then your test is flawed; CPython interns string literals that look like legal variable names, so if the string in question appears as a literal anywhere else in your program (including as the name of some class or function in some module you imported), it won't actually go away when you replace it. Similar implicit caches can occur if the literal string appears in any function, anywhere (it ends up being not only interned, but stored in the constants for that function).

**Update:** On testing, in an actual script, the reference count for `'surely'` when you hold onto a copy of it is `3`, which drops to `2` when you replace it with `'probably'`. Turns out constants are being cached even at global scope. The only reason the interactive interpreter doesn't exhibit this behavior is that it effectively `eval`s each line separately, so the constant cache is discarded when the `eval` completes.

And even if all that's not a problem, most (almost all) memory managers (CPython's specialized small object heap and the general heap it's built on) don't actually zero out memory when its released, so if you do look at the same address shortly after it really was released, it'll probably have pretty similar data in it.

Lastly, your `gc.collect()` call won't change anything except by coincidence (of whatever happens during `gc` possibly allocating memory by side-effect). `str` is not a garbage collected type, as it cannot contain references to other Python objects, so it's impossible for it to be a link in a reference cycle, and the CPython garbage collector is solely concerned with collecting cyclic garbage; CPython is reference counted, so anything that's not part of a reference cycle is cleaned up automatically and immediately when the last reference disappears.

The short answer this all leads up to is: **There is no way to determine, within CPython, non-heuristically, if a particular memory address has been released to the free store and made available for reuse.** CPython's memory management scheme is pure implementation detail, and exposing APIs at that level of detail would create compatibility concerns when people depended on them.

The closest you're going to get is using something like [the `tracemalloc` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html#module-tracemalloc) to perform basic snapshotting and compute differences in the snapshot. That's not going to give you a window into whether a specific address is still in use though AFAICT; at best it can tell you where an address that's *definitely* in use was allocated.

The other approach (specific to CPython) you can use is to just check the reference counts before replacing the object; `sys.getrefcount` for a given name/attribute reports `2`, then `del`ing (or rebinding) that name/attribute will release it (assuming no threads that might create additional references between the test and the `del`/rebind). You expect `2`, not `1`, because calling `sys.getrefcount` creates a temporary reference to the object in question. If it reports a number greater than `2`, `del`ing/rebinding could still lead to the object being deleted eventually when the cyclic garbage collectors runs, if the object was part of a reference cycle, but for a reference count of `2` (or `1` for something otherwise unnamed, e.g. `sys.getrefcount(''.join(('f', '9'))` or the like), the behavior will be deterministic.

Comment: Yeah I know that Id is only for CPython and that sizeof roughly estimates but it works for just a simple experiment. As I said in the comment up to now is all like I should be the question is if I can understand if a memory address is used or not...

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation about `gc`:

> ... the collector supplements the reference counting already used in Python...

And from `gc.is_tracked()`:

> Returns True if the object is currently tracked by the garbage collector, False otherwise. As a general rule, instances of atomic types aren’t tracked and instances of non-atomic types (containers, user-defined objects…) are.

Strings are *not* tracked by the garbage collector:

```
In [1]: import gc

In [2]: test = 'surely'
Out[2]: 'surely'

In [3]: gc.is_tracked(test)
Out[3]: False
```

Looking at the documentation, there doesn't seem to be a method for accessing the reference counting *from within* the language.

Note that at least for me, using `string_at` *doesn't work* from the interactive interpreter. It does work in a script.

Comment: Note on `string_at` not working interactively: Using `ipython` as an interactive interpreter is likely injecting a *lot* of noise into your measurements, which would explain why `string_at` was even less functional than you might expect; `ipython` invokes a *ton* of code just to display the prompt (and per line output), and even if that didn't somehow mess with things, it has background thread(s) that perform various actions that are essentially guaranteed to trigger frequent allocations (and correspondingly, frequent cyclic garbage collections).

Comment: @ShadowRanger That's why I used plain old Python itself instead of IPython, hoping that would be less of an issue. But no luck. OTOH, as Python programmers we probably shouldn't try to poke so deep  under the covers. The details of memory management are surely mostly an implementation detail instead of a part of the language.

Comment: K. Just noticed the `ipython` in the answer and thought I'd mention it. On looking at the output from running this in a script, it looks like the script is keeping references to `'surely'` around; turns out the constant cache exists at global scope too, not just function scope, so any `str` literal in a script is effectively immortal (barring extreme measures), and you'd never see the memory freed up for reuse. The interactive interpreter releases the memory because it's effectively `eval`ing each line in a separate frame, so constants expire after each line.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Interesting. Suddenly a "simple scripting language" isn't so simple anymore. :-)